# Does Ballerina support or plan to support XQuery and/or XSLT?

Tags: ballerina

I am currently evaluating ballerina features for its potential to replace existing ESB services.   When I think about all of the existing integrations I would need to migrate they have a great deal of transformation logic written in XQuery.   I can see that ballerina would do transformation cleaner in its native language.  But for existing services it would be an easier migration path if I did not have to rewrite some of these complex transformations.

I reviewed the docs and ballerina central and can't seem to find anything referencing this.  Are there plans to support it?

Comment: Already reported as an issue: https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/4224 You can direct feature requests to https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues

Answer (score 0):

Ballerina now have an XSLT module. Here's the [documentation](https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/api-docs/ballerina/xslt/index.html)